# Returning map sorted by key from cts:*-value-co-occurrences in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I have a hundred documents like the following  where n=1 to 100.

```
<root>
<parent>
<child id="n">sometext</child>
</parent>
</root>
```

I am using the following query to fetch a map of (id,uri).

```
cts:element-attribute-value-co-occurrences(xs:QName("child"),xs:QName("id"),xs:QName("xdmp:document"),(),("ascending","map",
     "collation-2=http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint"),())
```

I am expecting the map to be sorted by the key by specifying the 'ascending' option.But the map returned is not sorted.In fact every time the document with `id=53` comes at the top.
How do I get a sorted map?

Answer (score 2):

The map:map is implemented as a HashMap, so you won't be able to get sorted keys out of it, regardless of the method or order of adding the keys. Use the non-map response, and iterate over it with a FLWOR to handle it in the order that is returned by the function..

HTH!

Comment: Thanks.That helps. The reason I want a map is that there might be multiple documents sharing the same id(not hinted in the original example). Hence, for non-map responses I will have to do a group-by operation which I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: Tough choice: either use map and do your own sorting, or use the cooc XML and do your own grouping. You might have to try both to see which one is faster. Also consider https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-tuples which gives you a sequence of json:array sorted by values. Working with that may be faster than working with cooc XML.

Answer (score 2):

The results are not sorted because a map:map item is a species of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table and so the keys are in a pseudo-random order by definition.

You could rebuild the map as a [json:object](https://docs.marklogic.com/json:object) sorted by value, or by `cts:frequency`. Possibly the lexicon functions should use `json:object` instead of `map:map`, but as of 7.0-3 they do not. You could send that idea to MarkLogic support as an RFE, if you like.